# Using for range variable as function argument while looping through map of maps

Tags: c++, for-loop, reference, stdmap

I'm trying to loop through a map of maps and pass each pair to a function which modifies the contents.  When I try to compile the below code, I get the following error with respect to the `item` range variable declaration:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >'
     for(std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>& index : names)
```

When I try to use `auto&` to declare range variable index, the error moves from the range variable declaration to the function call `incrementAndPrintIt(index);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void incrementAndPrintIt(std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>& value)
{
    for(auto& j : value.second) {
        j.second = j.second + 1;
        std::cout << "j:  " << j.second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    //initialize a map of maps
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> names = {{"women",{{"Rita",2}}},{"men",{{"Jack",4}}}};

    for(std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>& index : names) {
        incrementAndPrintIt(index);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for(std::pair<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>& index : names)
```

In a `std::map`, the map's key, the first value in the pair, is a constant value.

This should be:

```
 for(std::pair<const std::string, std::map<std::string, int>>& index : names)
```

`incrementAndPrintIt()`'s parameter should also be adjusted to the same.

It's easy to use `auto` to avoid this entire headache in the first place:

```
 for(auto& index : names)
```

But this doesn't help with `incrementAndPrintIt()`'s parameter. However it doesn't need map's key, so you can simply pass `index.second` to it, and save a lot of wear and tear on your keyboard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

void incrementAndPrintIt(std::map<std::string, int> &value)
{
    for(auto& j : value) {
        j.second = j.second + 1;
        std::cout << "j:  " << j.second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    //initialize a map of maps
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> names = {{"women",{{"Rita",2}}},{"men",{{"Jack",4}}}};

    for(auto& index : names) {
        incrementAndPrintIt(index.second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You must admit: this is much simpler, isn't it?